# style of semaphore usage on execution order between the different instructions of P1 and P2

Tags: javascript, wordpress, windows, operating-system

Considering two processes P1 and P2. If we wanted to define an execution order between the different instructions of P1 and P2, then which style of semaphore usage you would apply?

Mutual exclusion style.
Waiting style.

Considering two processes P1 and P2. If we wanted to define an execution order between the different instructions of P1 and P2, then which style of semaphore usage you would apply
such that :
the difference between them lies in their focus:

Mutual Exclusion Style: Primarily concerned with ensuring that only one process can execute a critical section at a time to prevent conflicts.

Waiting Style: Primarily concerned with coordinating the order of execution between processes or threads, often involving waiting for specific conditions or signals before proceeding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.